# Compiler for ARM64 on ubuntu mate 18.04 LTS

Tags: java, compiling, raspberrypi, arm64

My question is about software compiler for arm64.

I would like to install java,c++,c# compiler using ubuntu mate 18.04 LTS on my raspberry pi, ARM64.

I was try few compilers but cannot install on ARM64. Use monodevelop before but this slow in process and sometimes make stuck and lagging.

Does anyone know and kindly advise me what are suggested /recommended suitable compiler to do a programming on arm64?

Thank you

Comment: I guess that would be e.g. `gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu` https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu ... Full list : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=aarch64&searchon=names

Comment: thanks @KnudLarsen. Does gcc can design GUI like monodevelop if you know? example: text area or button?

Comment: @Syairah you are confusing a few things here. Monodevelop is an IDE (integrated development environment) for C#, F#, etc. GCC is a *compiler* suite for different langauges, not a development environment. It is not a graphical tool!
What are you trying to do here? What kind of application do you want to develop and what languages are you familiar with?